# Passing C++ classes across a Dll boundry

Tags: c++, dll, export

I'm trying to wrap my head around what you can and can't do across the C++ Dll boundary when Binary application interface may not be the same.

So as I understand it so far it can be broken down into several scenarios outlined below.

Sorry it's more pseudo code than actual compliable code, which would have all the correct __declspec dllexport/dllimport. I'm more concerned about the concept and correct strategy rather than a specific instance.

**Scenario 1: The class passed across the dll boundary should be identical, we are ok**

[image: no description]

**Scenario 2: The class passed across the dll boundary might be different, not advised!**

[image: no description]

**Scenario 3: The data being based is privative to c, so we are still ok**

[image]

**Discussion**

So I believe what I've drawn up to be correct, correct me if I am wrong.

When we have scenario 2:

- is it possible to populate a Foo object in our executable that comes from our DLL?
- would this never work except by coincidence using the raw class.

for example in the DLL Code if we had a function for the client to call

```
void getFoo(Foo& clientsFoo){
    //Still will not work because setValue function 
    //might not align with the dll's version of setValue
    clientsFoo.setValue(myFoo.member1); 
}
```

So is the way people actually do this by abstracting the class they want to populate

Shared virtual interface

```
class IFoo{
    public:
        virtual ~IFoo() = 0;
        virtual setValue(const char* name) = 0;
}

IFoo::~IFoo(){}
```

Then in the DLL we would then change our function that the client could call to be

```
void getFoo(IFoo& clientsFoo){
    //This now works because the clients code will be called
    clientsFoo.setValue(myFoo.member1); 
}
```

However I assume this only works if the interface only has functions that take/output privative types?

Comment: Either (a) pass C++ objects but you must build every component with exactly the same tool-chain; (b) pass only C types but you still need to address using the heap across the ABI boundary; (c) use COM.

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes, (a) is scenario 1, (b) is scenario 3 and COM is a shared virtual interface? Unless I'm misunderstanding you just highlighted what is in my outline above?

Comment: Yup except I added conditions (1) exactly the same tool-chain as the layout of `std` library objects (or your own objects) may/well differ (this also includes debug/release); (2) the need to be very careful when allocating and free memory as the different modules may/will have distinct heaps so you can't allocate in one module and free in another; and (3) you are reinventing COM so just use COM.